# Unable to fetch Data from database using Spring Hibernate maven

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, h2

Program is executing Select query is also running in console but not displaying on page,please check the program and correct me thank you

Output

[Output of the Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZottV.png)
product class

```
   package com.ecom.Model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {

      @Id
      @Column
      private int id;

      @Column
      @NotNull
      @Size(min=1,message="is required")
      private String product_name;
      @Column
      @NotNull
      @Size(min=1,message="is required")
      private String manufacturer;
      @Column
      private int stock;
      @Column
      private String description;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getProduct_name() {
        return product_name;
    }
    public void setProduct_name(String product_name) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
    }
    public String getManufacturer() {
        return manufacturer;
    }
    public void setManufacturer(String manufacturer) {
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
    }
    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }
    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
    public Product(int id, String product_name, String manufacturer, int stock, String description) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.product_name = product_name;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.stock = stock;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Product()
    {}
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Product [id=" + id + ", product_name=" + product_name + ", manufacturer=" + manufacturer + ", stock="
                + stock + ", description=" + description + "]";
    }
}
```

product controller class
In controller i have created the model to save the data into model with the help of Product reference calling getAllProduct method.

```
 package com.ecom.Controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import com.ecom.DAO.ProductDAO;
import com.ecom.Model.Product;

@Controller
public class ProductController {

    //injecting Dependecy
    @Autowired
    private ProductDAO productDAO;




       @RequestMapping("/ProductList")
    public String  ListProducts(Model theModel)
    {
        List<Product> theProducts = productDAO.getAllProduct();

        theModel.addAttribute("products",theProducts);

        return "productlist";
        }

    @RequestMapping("/ProductForm")
    public String ProductForm(Model theModel)
    {   
         Product theProduct = new Product();

         theModel.addAttribute("addProduct", theProduct);

         return "productform";
    } 

     @RequestMapping("/saveProduct")
     public String saveProduct(@ModelAttribute("addProduct") Product theProdut)
     { 
         productDAO.addProducts(theProdut);  

         return "productform";
     }

}
```

Product Dao Implementation

```
     package com.ecom.DAOImplementation;



import java.util.List;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.ecom.DAO.ProductDAO;
import com.ecom.Model.Product;

@Repository("ProductDAO")
public class ProductImpl implements ProductDAO {

      @Autowired
      private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

      @Transactional
      public List<Product> getAllProduct() {
          Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

          Query<Product> theQuery = currentSession.createQuery("from Product",Product.class);

          List<Product> products = theQuery.getResultList();

          return products;
        }


     @javax.transaction.Transactional
    public void addProducts(Product theProdut) 
    {
        Session currentSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();    

        System.out.println("Adding Product");
        currentSession.save(theProdut);
        System.out.println("Success");
    }

}

Jsp page


<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
   <table border="1px">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Product Name</th>
                    <th>Manufacturer</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                </tr>

                <c:forEach var="tempCustomer" items="${products}">
                <tr>
                   <td> ${tempCustomer.id} </td>      
                   <td> ${tempCustomer.product_name} </td>
                   <td> ${tempCustomer.manufacturer} </td>
                   <td> ${tempCustomer.stock} </td>
                   <td> ${tempCustomer.description} </td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>

    </table>    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just tried to set this up by creating a sample list as shown below.

```
    @RequestMapping("/ProductList")
    public String  ListProducts(Model theModel)
    {
        List<Product> theProducts = productDAO.getAllProduct();
        Product product = new Product(1,"pro-1","man-1",10,"pro-1 desc");
        theProducts.add(product); 
        product = new Product(2,"pro-2","man-2",10,"pro-2 desc");
        theProducts.add(product); 
        product = new Product(3,"pro-3","man-3",10,"pro-3 desc");
        theProducts.add(product); 
        product = new Product(4,"pro-4","man-4",10,"pro-4 desc");
        theProducts.add(product); 
        product = new Product(5,"pro-5","man-5",10,"pro-5 desc");
        theProducts.add(product); 
        theModel.addAttribute("products",theProducts);
        return "productlist";
   }
```

The JSP page `productlist.jsp` is `as is`. No changes done. I get the output as below.

[image: Product List]

You can perhaps try putting up debug statements to see if the `theProducts` is correctly populated.

Comment: Thank you for your reply I tried to print data from database,data is successfully displayed in console ..but not displaying in  jsp page.      here is the output :Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_1_, product0_.description as descript2_1_, product0_.manufacturer as manufact3_1_, product0_.product_name as product_4_1_, product0_.stock as stock5_1_ from product product0_

[Product [id=1, product_name=Wrist Watch, manufacturer=Timex, stock=12, description=water Proof], Product [id=2, product_name=casual, manufacturer=Sonata, stock=10, description=water Resist]]

Comment: All code is correct then also why not giving output on jsp page ?

Comment: Have you tried printing the list on JSP page to see if it is reaching there? `<%
 System.out.println("JSP ="+request.getAttribute("products"));
%>`

Comment: printing JSP =null

Comment: So, the data is not reaching your jsp. That's why a problem. Can you check all your spring configuration?

Comment: Can you check my code Here is my githhub [Backend](https://github.com/pritamcc/Ecommerce/tree/master/FinalProjects/EcommerceBackend/src/main/java/com/ecom/Controller) , [frontend](https://github.com/pritamcc/Ecommerce/tree/master/FinalProjects/EcommerceFrontend/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/view)